# (my)SQL only solution to show available time slots from agenda system

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

**Description**
I'm making a agenda system with (multiple) agenda's where you can reserve a time slot of a variable time (10/15/20 or 30 minutes) during a selected period of time (eg. 9:00am till 11:00am on mondays and 10:30am till 3:00pm)

Off course I can do this in PHP and poll the appointments and availability table for every time slot available for every date being showed, but some how that sounds a little bit server intensive. So I was wondering if there was a way to produce a mySQL result relation which shows the time-slots and availability tupples....

**Database/table setup**
This is the table setup which I thought was necessary.

***appointments*** `holds the appointments already made`
id | int `unique id`
agenda_id | int `unique id identifying the agenda`
start | date_time `start of the appointment`
end | date_time `end of the appointment`
*some more descriptive fields*

**availability** `when are there which time slots available`
agenda_id | int `identifying which agenda`
day_of_the_week | int `which day, eg 1=monday`
start_time | time  `e.g. 09:00:00`
end_time | time `e.g. 11:00:00`
time_slot | int `how long are the time slots? e.g. 10minutes`

( remarks:
If necesssary the time_slots field can also be hard coded;
The system runs on a MySQL database, if necessary we can switch to postgresql
)

**Desired result**
Given a date `2013-02-21` and an agenda_id `1` (and if necessary the time slot `15`) and a working day from 8:00 to 18:00;
how can I create a mysql query, view or stored procedure to produce the following table/relation:

```
date       | 8:00 | 8:15 | 8:30 | 8:45 | 9:00 | 9:15 | ..... | 17:15 | 17:30 | 17:45 |
2013-02-21 |   0  |  0   |   0  |  0   |  1   |   2  | ..... |   2   |   2   |   1   |
```

Where:
0 = not bookable
1 = available, you can book this timeslot
2 = not available, an appointment exists

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to switch to PostgreSQL, you probably want to make sure you're on version 9.2 (or later), so that you can take full advantage of [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) and [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE).  A GiST index is very useful with this sort of data, but an exclusion constraint will automatically create one, so you probably don't need to declare one explicitly.  If you want to list available openings within a certain range, the [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) function could be used to join candidate times against the existing schedule with [`NOT x && y`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) to filter out the unavailable times.

I'm not sure what the equivalent is in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pivot the appointments and compare to the availability.  This is a join and aggregation query, with conditional aggregations.  The following is the idea:

```
select agendaId, const.thedate,
       sum(case when thedate + interval 8 hour + interval 0 minute between ap.start and ap.end
                then 1 else 0
           end) as "8:00",
       sum(case when thedate + interval 8 hour + interval 15 minute between ap.start and ap.end
                then 1 else 0
           end) as "8:15",
       . . .
from (select date('2013-02-21' ) as thedate) const cross join
     Availability a left outer join
     Appointments ap
     on a.AgendaId = ap.AgendaId and
        const.day_of_the_week = weekday(const.thedate)        
where date(ap.start) = const.thedate 
group by AgendaId
```